# Program doesn't seem to be storing the data into the text file

Tags: java

The program below is meant to take in a csv file and work out certain data but it isn't saving the array data to the file so it can be read.
I think the problem seems to be with this line,  if (localIPArray[i] == ip) { , as it doesn't seem to think the data is == when a valid ip is inputted.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Program

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class writ1Program {

    public static File inputFile() throws IOException { // input method

        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter File name: ");
        String name = x.next();
        File file = new File(name);
        return file;

    }

    public static void showAnomalous(File file) { // displaying anomoloys data method
        File dataFile = new File("AnomalousData.csv");
    }

    public static void sortDate(File file) { // show data between 2 dates method

    }

    public static void sortIP(File file) throws IOException { // show data of a specific IP address method

        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter Ip address of user who's data you would like to see: ");// aks for input
        String ip = x.nextLine();
        Scanner y = new Scanner(new File("PCAP Data.csv")); // file to read from

        File ipFile = new File("IPFile.csv");// creates new file
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(ipFile);
        Scanner Reader = new Scanner(ipFile);

        List<String> date = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> localIP = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> remoteAsn = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> flows = new ArrayList<>();

        // https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-read-csv-file-in-java
        String line = "";
        String sliptBy = ",";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("PCAP Data.csv"));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] data = line.split(sliptBy);
            // System.out.println(data);
            date.add(data[0]);
            // System.out.print(date);
            localIP.add(data[1]);
            // System.out.print(localIP);
            remoteAsn.add(data[2]);
            // System.out.print(remoteAsn);
            flows.add(data[3]);
            // System.out.print(flows);
        }

        String[] dateArray = date.toArray(new String[0]);
        String[] localIPArray = localIP.toArray(new String[0]);
        String[] remoteAsnArray = remoteAsn.toArray(new String[0]);
        String[] flowsArray = flows.toArray(new String[0]);
        // System.out.print(dateArray[0]);
        // System.out.print(flowsArray[1]);

        for (int i = 0; i < localIPArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(localIPArray[i]);
            if (localIPArray[i] == ip) {
                fileWriter.write(String.valueOf(dateArray[i]) + ",");
                fileWriter.write(String.valueOf(localIPArray[i]) + ",");
                fileWriter.write(String.valueOf(remoteAsnArray[i]) + ",");
                fileWriter.write(String.valueOf(flowsArray[i]) + ",");
                fileWriter.write("\n");

            }

            // while (Reader.hasNextLine()) {
            // String newIpData = Reader.nextLine();
            // System.out.println(newIpData);
            // }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { // main method

        File file = inputFile();
        sortIP(file);
    }

}
```

The file that is being  looks like this:

Date,Local IP,Remote_ASN,Flows

07/01/2022,10,701,1

07/01/2022,10,714,1

07/01/2022,10,1239,1

07/01/2022,10,1680,1

07/01/2022,10,2514,1

07/01/2022,10,3320,1

07/01/2022,10,3561,13

07/01/2022,10,4134,3

07/01/2022,10,5617,2

07/01/2022,10,6478,1

07/01/2022,10,6713,1

07/01/2022,10,7132,1

Comment: Always use try-with-resources when opening files with IO classes